# How can I use javascript to sort divs by numbered classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<pre>
    <div>
      <div class="abc grid-row">
        <div class="grid-cell position_2">
            <img src="#">
        </div>
        <div class="grid-cell position_1">
            <img src="#">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="abc grid-row">
        <div class="grid-cell position_2">
            <img src="#">
        </div>
        <div class="grid-cell position_3">
            <img src="#">
        </div>
        <div class="grid-cell position_1">
            <img src="#">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="def grid-row">
        <div class="grid-cell position_2">
            <img src="#">
        </div>
        <div class="grid-cell position_1">
            <img src="#">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</pre>
```

I would like to iterate through each grid-row to sort the child divs by the position class in numerical order. So position_1 will always be the first child div in each grid row.

When I tried doing this with jQuery, the child divs were being sorted into other rows, which I need to prevent. How can I achieve this?

Comment: First you need to iterate over each `grid-row` then sort its `grid-cell`s

Comment: _"When I tried doing this with jQuery, the child divs were being sorted into other rows,"_ Perhaps show this code, so we can help fix what you've tried, rather than starting from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

uses `sort` on the `grid-cell` within each `grid-row`

```js
$('.grid-row').each(function() {
  var cells = $('.grid-cell', this).sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseInt(a.className.match(/[0-9]+/)[0]) > parseInt(b.className.match(/[0-9]+/)[0]);
  });
  $(this).html(cells);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="abc grid-row">
    <div class="grid-cell position_2">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell position_1">
      1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="abc grid-row">
    <div class="grid-cell position_2">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell position_3">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell position_1">
      1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="def grid-row">
    <div class="grid-cell position_2">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell position_1">
      1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked about a javascript solution, but you might consider looking at Flexbox too. You could do something like this:

```css
.abc {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  }
```

```html
<div class="abc grid-row">
    <div class="grid-cell position_2" style="order:2">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell position_3" style="order:3">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell position_1" style="order:1">
      1
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.grid-row').each(function(){
    var $row = $(this), $cells = $();  //create an empty list
    for(var i=0; i<5; ++i){
        //append the items for each "position" to the list
        $.merge($cells, $row.find("> .grid-cell.position_"+i));
    }
    //append the cells in the right order to the row
    $row.append($cells);
})
```

or

```
//a utility to fetch the position
function getPosition(node){
    var m = node.className.match(/\bposition_(\d+)\b/);
    return +(m && m[1] || -Infinity);
}

$('.grid-row').each(function(){
    var $row = $(this);
    $row.find('> .grid-cell').sort(function(a, b){
        return getPosition(a) - getPosition(b);
    }).appendTo($row);
});
```